# How long should windshield wipers last in Colorado and how often should I replace them?

Tags: windshield-wipers

I totally realize this is a VERY subjective question but I'm wondering how long wiper blades should last in Colorado.  We have fairly hot summers and can have very cold winters (albeit not for long stretches).  The climate is very dry.

I've read [What wears out windshield wipers?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/16264/what-wears-out-windshield-wipers) and realize that running blades on dry windshields is less than ideal as well as dry climates will dry out rubber faster.

If my current wear and tear is "normal," how often should I be replacing them?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As you stated it is difficult to say how long wipers last due to various usage and environmental conditions. One thing that can be agreed on is that they need to be replaced when they cease to clear the window. Replacement should occur when streaks or unwiped areas  reduce visibility enough to be a safety concern. I typically change mine in the fall. I install new winter blades at that time. Due to the road salt and sand that gets applied to the roads they usually only last 4 to 5 months. In the spring I install regular beam type blades. These will usually last 2 seasons before they begin to streak.  If you are in an area where snow and ice  aren't an issue I would plan on once a year. The problem with wiper condition is you don't realize they are worn until you need them and then it's too late.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I think 6 months is maybe what I'm seeing, but I honestly can't remember.  I probably should start keeping track....